# File Purpose and Usage Questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, too-localized

I've often had to go search for files that I've found running on my computer, and I want to find out what they are, and if they're ok.  I usually do a lot of googling to find the answer, but have found that there are many of those soul-sucking sell-me-a-driver-program-websites that key off of those key filenames.  I think it would be a positive for the whole Internet, and Super User specifically, if we allowed a repository of those to build up here.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/331246/what-does-the-process-oobechk-exe-do-closed) was closed as "Too Localized", when it obviously wasn't, since many users would have that file on their computer, and searches are done on it all the time.

I hope people will allow these questions to flourish (and vote to reopen that one).

Note:  I do not want anyone just creating these questions out of thin air, just in the onesy-twosy fashion that they will naturally come about in, like any other category of question.

I have created the tag [process-files](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process-files) for these types of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree, trying to find information about these files can be pretty tricky at times. Reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue as with the computer virus questions: We don't want one (or more) questions per virus. In this case, it's possibly non-virus processes, but the problem's the same: It requires hundreds of thousands of very narrow topics to build a useful body of knowledge.

Rephrase as *How can I find out what a process running on my machine does and where it's from?* and live with results not specifically tailored to your use case. You need to do some thinking, but the topic will be actually useful to others.

Comment: I think the main answer for your rephrased question will be "Google It".

Comment: @Lance Or "Ask on SU and hope you get a good answer before the question's closed" :-)

Comment: Well, the problem is, "How can I find out what it does" is *really* hard to answer for any process, isn't it? :)